# Using multiple LayerIDs in Legend

Tags: layers, legend, wpf, arcgis-runtime

This should be simple, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do it. I have a legend that is bound to my map that contains several layers. I do not want all of the layers to appear on my Legend so I am using LayerIDs. The problem is that I do not know how to use multiple ones in the LayerIDs. Below is my code:

XAML(Legend):

```
<esri:Legend Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"
                         LayerIDs="CalvertCity, WaterValves"
                         LayerItemsMode="Tree"
                         ShowOnlyVisibleLayers="False">
                    <esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
                                </CheckBox>
                                <Slider Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Layer.Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                    <esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
                </esri:Legend>
```

XAML(ESRI Maps):

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Background="#FFE3E3E3" WrapAround="True"  MouseRightButtonDown="MyMap_MouseRightButtonDown" Extent="-9834972.92753924,4441899.425293319,-9833977.88119163, 4442762.485358352">
                <esri:Map.Layers>
                    <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />
                    <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="CandidateGraphicsLayer">
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Stroke="Gray"  RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="#77FF0000" Margin="0,0,0,5" >
                                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect/>
                                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#DDFFFFFF" Stroke="DarkGray" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Margin="10,10,10,15" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,20,30,30">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [Address]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                    </esri:GraphicsLayer>
                    <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="CalvertCity" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer"/>
                    <esri:FeatureLayer ID="WaterValves" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer/0" Renderer="{StaticResource MySimpleRenderer}"
                                                  OutFields="WVAL_ID,SIZE,WVAL_USE,WVAL_TYPE,OPENS,TURNS" MouseLeftButtonUp="FeatureLayer_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                </esri:Map.Layers>                
            </esri:Map>
```

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally answered my own question. I put the comma in there to explain that I wanted both of those layers and that is actually how you do it.

```
LayerIDs="CalvertCity, WaterValves"
```